# Pervasive SQL query

Tags: sql, pervasive

Does anyone have a query to search all columns in all tables in a Pervasive database for a specific value?

I am struggling to find any info on this.

Seems easy to do in sql server but not with Pervasive.

Answer (score 2):

--returns a list of all tables sorted by table name:
Select * from X$File order by xf$name

--returns a list of all columns (in order) and their attributes for a table called "Person":
select X$Field.* from X$Field, X$File 
where xe$File = xf$id and xf$name = 'Person' and xe$DataType < 200 
order by xe$offset

You could use some sort of stored procedure to run through them all. This is a SQL server stored proc that you might be able to use as a guide.

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

Comment: I dont suppose anyone would have such a stored procedure, Im a noob and have limited time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a stored procedure.  You can do it with this query:

```
select x$file.xf$name, X$Field.* from X$Field, X$File 
where xe$File = xf$id and 
xe$DataType < 200 
and xe$name = '<Column Name>'
order by xe$offset
```

Changing  to the name of the column you are looking for.
For example, to find a column named "Name", you would use the statement:

```
select x$file.xf$name, X$Field.* from X$Field, X$File 
where xe$File = xf$id and 
xe$DataType < 200 
and xe$name = 'Name'
order by xe$offset
```

and the results are:

```
Xf$Name                 Xe$Id   Xe$File   Xe$Name                Xe$DataType   Xe$Offset   Xe$Size   Xe$Dec   Xe$Flags
====================   ======   =======   ====================   ===========   =========   =======   ======   ========
Course                     86        13   Name                             0           0         7        0          1
Dept                       92        14   Name                             0           0        20        0          1
Class                      68        12   Name                             0           4         7        0          1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I dont need to search for Column name. I need to search each entry in all columns in all tables.

Comment: So you're basically trying to do a full text search of every single column in every single table in a database?

Comment: What version of Pervasive are you using?

Comment: Yes Mirtheil, exactly.

Version 8.00.114.000